# Apply styling on parent when interacting with child Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I want to remove the shadow of parent div when the checkbox is checked. Is this possible with only tailwind?

```
<div class="shadow  peer">
   <input class="peer-checked:shadow-none"/>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible via CSS as you only only access parent -> child and not child -> parent.

Tailwind can only do what CSS can do:

**element element**: div p
Selects all `<p>` elements inside `<div>` elements

**element>element**: div > p
Selects all `<p>` elements where the parent is a `<div>` element

**element+element**: div + p
Selects the first `<p>` element that is placed immediately after `<div>` elements

**element1~element2**: p ~ ul
Selects every `<ul>` element that is preceded by a `<p>` element

To change parent classes you would need a `JavaScript` implementation to add that:

```
<div class="shadow">
   <input type="checkbox" onchange="this.parentNode.classList.toggle('shadow')"/>
</div>
```

You should do this in JS component and not via inline JavaScript.